# IQueryable.Skip And IQueryable.Take Upper Bound

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework to query a database and i use the following:

```
context
    .MyTable
    .Where(...)
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .Skip((int)numberOfItemsToSkip)
    .Take((int)numberOfItemsToTake)
    .ToArray();
```

My question is about the part `Skip((int)numberOfItemsToSkip)`. It only accepts an `Int32` argument which has an upper bound of `Int32.MaxValue`. Now, what if the `MyTable` contains more than `Int32.MaxValue` records. The reason i say this is because the database i have is HUGE and grows substantially and that's why i came across the case that `Int32.MaxValue` might not be enough. My database is hosted on SQL Server.

So, is there any built-in way to pass a `Int64` argument instead? I can go ahead and do something manual, but my question is about something from within Entity Framework.

Comment: So, you have a result set numbering in the billions of rows and you think it's a reasonable use-case for people to be paging through all of those rows? Normally, it would be expected that other filtering would reduce the number of results down to "human" levels such that paging makes sense, or you wouldn't be using a paging style of data access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to repeat `Skip` several times:

```
context
    .MyTable
    .Where(...)
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)//you forgot it
    .Skip(numberOfItemsToSkip1)
    .Skip(numberOfItemsToSkip2)
    .Take(numberOfItemsToTake)
    .ToArray();
```

Resulted SQL (EF 6.1.3, SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Table]
    WHERE ....
    ORDER BY ...
    OFFSET numberOfItemsToSkip1 + numberOfItemsToSkip2 ROWS FETCH NEXT numberOfItemsToTake ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: What is the effect of this as far as the SQL query that Entity Framework generates?

Comment: I did try it on SQL Server 2008 R2 with EF 6.0 and it generated this: WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > (numberOfItemsToSkip1 + numberOfItemsToSkip2)

Comment: At my case - different result: `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT`